# Oracle BIP OOTB SQL returning ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am facing  **ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row** error in one of my report. The report was build by previous vendor and it is a big SQL which seems like was generated by some tool and used in the report. I am having a tough time to figure out what's wrong. All the sub queries are either using aggregate functions or  ROWNUM = 1 to return 1 record.

Please see if you can give me any pointers to which part I need to focus on. I checked the log files generated by the BIP but it just narrowed down it to the dataset.

Due to large size of the file, I provide the SQL in this file:
[SQL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1doxDlgaWudp-ztnwzH9cXWXchwVmVX2y/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Now that's a query. I hope Larry Ellison sends you a case of fine champagne every year. Oracle error messages usually indicate where in the query things went wrong. Do you have that information?

Comment: No, there is no specific information about it.

Comment: You should rewrite that query, it is a real hot mess.

Comment: Thats how i got it. Lets see if client is willing to pay for man hours for rewriting :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to scan the query line by line and check *all subqueries* that do **not** select an *aggregated function* (e.g. `MIN(..)`) and don't contain the  `ROWNUM = 1` limitation.

Example

```
                (
                    SELECT
                        ( ko.extn_attribute_timestamp006 )
                    FROM
                        moo_ref_entities ko
                    WHERE
                        ko.extn_attribute_number001 = lea.id
                        AND ko.attribute_category = 'RenewalAndOtherOptions_c'
                        AND nvl(ko.extn_attribute_timestamp003, sysdate) >= sysdate
                        AND ko.extn_attribute_timestamp005 = (
                            SELECT
                                MIN(ko.extn_attribute_timestamp005)
                            FROM
                                moo_ref_entities ko
                            WHERE
                                ko.extn_attribute_number001 = lea.id
                                AND ko.attribute_category = 'RenewalAndOtherOptions_c'
                                AND nvl(ko.extn_attribute_timestamp003, sysdate) >= sysdate
                        )
                ) AS option1_exc,
```

This is a typical trap as you constrain the `extn_attribute_timestamp005` with a `MIN` subquery, but if you have *ties* in the timestamps you get exact the error you observe.

Comment: Thanks @Marmite. This was the exact issue. The were two records with the same dates and it was causing error. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SELECT nested in a SELECT list that isn't guaranteed to yield just one row.

```sql
(
    SELECT FL.lookup_code
    FROM fnd_lookups FL
            ,hz_organization_profiles HO1
        WHERE ho1.party_id = LEA.extn_attribute_number010
            AND FL.lookup_code = HO1.extn_attribute_char035
            AND FL.lookup_type = 'FND_SALES_CATEGORY'
) AS Sales_Category
```

It wouldn't have been hard for somebody to INSERT something to that `fnd_lookups` table to make that subquery yield more than one row.  You could go for `AND ROWNUM=1` or `SELECT MAX(FL.lookup_code) lookup_code` to see if it helps.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion. I will look into it. Thanks.